# Importing coordinates from Google Maps as CSV into QGIS, but points are displaying in wrong location

Tags: qgis

I'm using QGIS and am trying to import coordinates pulled from Google Maps as CSV but they are displaying in the wrong location. They should be showing up in CA, however they are only displaying in the ocean off the west coast of Africa. I have tried changing projections and CRS but nothing so far has worked.

Comment: Can you provide some example points, along with the CRS they should be in?

Comment: JGH - actualy, yes that solution worked for me! Thank you!